# How to print section of html page as pdf

Tags: html, pdf

Basically, I have a users cart that I want to be either saved as a pdf/printed as a pdf or perhaps emailed on a button click (the emailing obviously couldn’t be done on a button click).

I’ve tried setting up a new web page, that uses java scripts session storage and JSON parse to get the information from a users shopping basket and display it on a new page. However, this is proving difficult.

So is it possible to save a dynamical product section of an HTML page like a users shopping basket as a pdf or better yet print it?

If it can’t be done, is there a better way of other than the session storage of JavaScript to display captures information from a previous page on a new page?

Comment: You'll need a library like `PDF.js`, `PDFsharp` or `mPDF`, but yes, it is possible.

Comment: Do any of them allow for css styling to be saved? Or applied